# styling: how to override primeng tabmenu border-colors on active element

Tags: css, primeng

I currently have a global blue theme (saga-blue). I managed to change the text and bottom border color (to match the desired brand colors) by using simple css.

However, when a menu item is first selected, it gets this ugly blue-colored border behind it, as such:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjgd1.jpg

No matter what CSS I try, I can't manage to remove it. I can't find where it comes from when I inspect the element. Also, it gets removed as soon as I click anywhere else on the screen: it is just there for the first click on the item, goes away after any other click.

CSS that I have tried:

```css
.p-tabmenu .p-tabmenu-nav .p-tabmenuitem.p-highlight .p-menuitem-link {
    color: $brand-red;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    border-right: 0px !important;
}

.p-tabmenu .p-tabmenu-nav .p-tabmenuitem.p-highlight {
    color: $brand-red;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    border-right: 0px !important;
}
```

I also tried unsetting any property that had to do with 'left' or 'right' on the menuitem and menulink components - but the ugly blue border just keeps on showing. If anyone has any idea what kind of property this might be, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your style is not applied and you want to override the primeng default styling, you may need to use  `:host ::ng-deep`.

Another way of applying style to a PrimeNG component nested element, is to use the `styleClass` template property. It is not everytime efficient, you need to sometime force the css through the `!important` priority modifier. It is not the cleanest way, but there is few CSS properties that are inlined by calculation on some component.

For your specific problem, the .p-tabmenu (and subclasses) is playing with a mixin of focus, when the element is in focus state.

```
@mixin focused() {
    outline: $focusOutline;
    outline-offset: $focusOutlineOffset;
    box-shadow: $focusShadow;
}
```

You need to play with the property `box-shadow` to remove/modify this blurred color that you dislike with the advices I gave you on the primeng styling if it is not applied as you wished.

Don't forget the pseudo-class `:focus` while overriding the style.

You may have this kind of result to remove it completely.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-tabmenu .p-tabmenu-nav .p-tabmenuitem.p-highlight .p-menuitem-link:focus {
     box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried using `:host ::ng-deep` earlier, but in my case just overriding with normal classes is doing it (and when I use `:host ::ng-deep` it stops working so I am sticking to normal classes). Your code recommendation is correct, I missed the `:focus` part when I attempted to do it myslef. Now the blue box-shadow just appears for like 1ms on click, and disappears afterwards. I went over all possible pseudo-classes (at least the ones here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) but couldn't override it, but I guess I can tolerate this small on-click blue shadow. Thanks!

Comment: For what I see in the scss file of the tab menu the path of classes to override the style is 
`.p-tabmenu .p-tabmenu-nav .p-tabmenuitem .p-menuitem-link:focus`

 I saw that you use the `.p-highlight` but it seems to be not responsible of the box-shadow at all 

Source: _tabmenu.scss of the primeng source layout (theme designer)

Answer (score 1):

Try `outline: 0` this is something that defaults browsers do for accesibility mainly.